# Controlling Timer0 in ATmega328p

Tags: c, timer, delay, arduino-uno, bare-metal

I'm trying to create a blocking delay for the ATmega328p for my arduino uno R3. but I'm running into problems with my function.

I am not sure if it has something to do with my clock source. I set it as 8 MHz at the top of my script, but the problem persists.

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
```

Here's a snip of my delay function, it's configured for a 10 ms delay at 8 MHz and uses a delayTime counter to create a longer delay

```
/* 
 * Function to instantiate timer operations 
 */
void makeDelay(int delayTime){
  // Call the timer for delayTime successively
  //  resulting in delay of (configured delay) * timerDelay
  while(delayTime > 0){
    /* Set the TCNT reg for 10ms @ 8 MHz */
    TCNT0 = 0xB2;
    
    // Define the mode and prescaler values
    TCCR0A = 0x00;  // Normal mode
    TCCR0B = 0x05;  //  prescaler = 1024

    // loop until overflow
    while( (TIFR0 & (1 << TOV0) == 0) );

    // Stop the timer
    TCCR0B = 0;

    // clear the overflow
    TIFR0 = 0x01;

    // decrement the counter
    delayTime--;
  }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Arduino runtime library already uses TIMER0 for `mills()` implementation. You need to disable TIMER0 interrupts at least. And of course, you can't use `mills()` anymore if TIMER0 is reprogrammed.

Comment: @dimich

I just tried to do that with 

TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(TOIE0)

But it's still behaving the same way

Comment: Did you also stop the timer and clear overflow flag before calling the function? What the problem are you running into? The function hangs forever? Executes without delay? Delay is present but longer/shorter than expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program this waiting condition is wrong:

```c
(TIFR0 & (1 << TOV0) == 0)
```

Operator `==` has higher precedence than `&`. `(1 << TOV0) == 0` is evaluated first and it is always false. Thus `TIFR0 & 0` is always false too.
Rewrite the condition as

```c
((TIFR0 & (1 << TOV0)) == 0)
```

or

```c
((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) == 0)
```

You can use following formula to calculate `TCCNT0` register value for milliseconds:

```
Nticks = 256 - ms*F_CPU/1000/prescaler
```

As Timer0 is used by Arduino runtime library, you should disable it at first.

Entire sketch may be like this:

```c
#define MS2TICKS(ms) (256 - (ms)*(F_CPU/1000)/1024)

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  TCCR0B = 0;    // Stop timer
  TIMSK0 = 0;    // Disable timer interrupts
  TCCR0A = 0;    // Normal mode
  TIFR0  = ~0;   // Clear all interrupt flags
}

void my_delay()
{
  TCNT0 = MS2TICKS(10);
  TCCR0B = 0x05;       // Enable timer with prescaler 1024

  while ((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) == 0);

  TCCR0B = 0;         // Stop Timer0
  TIFR0 = _BV(TOV0);  // Clear overflow flag
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  my_delay();
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  my_delay();
}
```

It generates 10 ms pulses with 10 ms pauses on LED output.

Comment: That was the problem. Disabled the interrupts and corrected the while condition and it worked. Thanks